# Java: Access Class Method from Vector

Tags: java, class, methods, vector

I'm trying to access a class method from inside a vector. I create a new object, add it to a vector, and then try to call a method on the element the object was stored in

```
ClassObject newObj = new ClassObject (int var1, int var2);

Vector object_vector = new Vector<ClassObject>();

object_vector.add(newObj);

//This does work
newObj.classMethod();

//This does not work
object_vector.get(0).classMethod();
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: the error says "Cannot resolve method 'classMethod()'. program wont compile.

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I needed to type cast the vector.

```
//This Works
((ClassObject)object_vector.get(0)).classMethod();
```